# How to show a different text when another page is shown?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to show another text for every page of the ViewPager inside a TextView. But when the app is startet it isn't showing the text at all and when I change the page, only the default mode is shown.
I've put the following code inside of the `onCreate` in the `MainActivity`:

```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        final    TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.my_textview);

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    myTextView.setText("TextView1");
                case 1:
                    myTextView.setText("TextView2");
                case 2:
                    myTextView.setText("TextView3");
                default:
                    myTextView.setText("TextView");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `break` in your switch statement cases which will cause all the cases below the valid one to execute including the `default`

Also the TextView will not show anything in the beginning because you added the listener after the view is created so you could use `viewpager.getCurrentItem()` in your `onCreate()` to show the correct text for the first time

Comment: @SusanT.Erickson I've edited my answer to include the other problem

Answer (score 0):

No text is being shown when your application starts because no page has been selected meaning the onPageSelected method is never being fired.

The default block is always executed when a page is selected because after each case you never use the break keyword. This means that when case 0, case 1 or case 2 happens it will fall through to the default case.